# How do I turn OFF colors for ls output in Terminal on OSX

Tags: macos, colors, terminal, ls

my `ls` output colors all directories differently from files, regardless whether I type `ls` or `/bin/ls`. I don't have any `LS_COLOR` stuff set in `.bashrc` or related files that I can find.

How do I turn *off* these colors? (I am quite happy with just `ls -F`)

Thanks!

Comment: You may have `CLICOLOR` environment variable set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comment, OSX `ls` pays attention to **`CLICOLOR`**.  The [`ls` manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) page is the place to look.  It appears to be the same program as in [FreeBSD](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/ls.1.html), which uses the terminal database (in contrast to GNU ls).  Likewise, note that the variable is **`LSCOLORS`**, rather than **`LS_COLORS`**:

> **`CLICOLOR`**
>
> Use ANSI color sequences to distinguish file types.  See **`LSCOLORS`** below.  In addition
>   to the file types mentioned in the -F option some extra attributes (setuid bit set,
>   etc.) are also displayed.  The colorization is dependent on a terminal type with the
>   proper termcap(5) capabilities.  The default “cons25” console has the proper capabilities,
>   but to display the colors in an xterm(1), for example, the TERM variable must be
>   set to “xterm-color”.  Other terminal types may require similar adjustments.  Colorization
>   is silently disabled if the output isn't directed to a terminal unless the **`CLICOLOR_FORCE`** variable is defined.
>
> **`CLICOLOR_FORCE`**
>
> Color sequences are normally disabled if the output isn't directed to a terminal.  This
>   can be overridden by setting this flag.  The **`TERM`** variable still needs to reference a
>   color capable terminal however otherwise it is not possible to determine which color
>   sequences to use.
>
> **`TERM`**
>
> The **`CLICOLOR`** functionality depends on a terminal type with color capabilities.

The wording about "termcap(5)" is outdated; both FreeBSD and OSX have used terminfo databases for more than ten years.

The GNU [ls manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) page does say **`LS_COLORS`** (the two are not the same).  The [`dircolors` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dircolors.1.html) page makes an oblique reference to a "precompiled database" (this is unrelated to terminfo/termcap, and its use of `TERM` to get similar results is a source of confusion).

Comment: I did have CLICOLOR set -- until now I had no idea what it did. Thanks.