# Extra escape characters from ls command making life hard

Tags: linux, ls, ansi-escape

I want to issue a simple ls command and store the results in a file:

`ls -ltr equ* > ffile`

The file names show up with extra escape characters attached.  These show up plainly under some utilities (like vi), and not at all under others (like more).  Example:

```
-rw------- 1 me 9607LPET  72680 Apr 10 12:00 ^[[0m^[[00mequ_00020.dat^[[0m
-rw------- 1 me 9607LPET  72680 Apr 10 12:00 ^[[00mequ_00021.dat^[[0m
-rw------- 1 me 9607LPET 356110 Apr 10 12:00 ^[[00mequ_00065.dat^[[0m
-rw------- 1 me 9607LPET  60253 Apr 10 12:00 ^[[00mequ_00067.dat^[[0m
-rw------- 1 me 9607LPET  83656 Apr 10 12:00 ^[[00mequ_00068.dat^[[0m
```

Anyway, these characters are detected by almost any tool I might use to process this file list.  They are making it very difficult to process the file names. 
How do I get rid of them?  What are they there for in the first place?

EDIT: This question has been flagged as a duplicate of another question that also involved getting rid of colors in the `ls` output.  However, I maintain that getting rid of the colors is a single solution *to two distinct problems*.  The other question is specifically about colors in the first place.  This one is not.  A user can have the exact problem I just had and still have no idea whatsoever that he should be looking at other questions involving color in `ls` output.  I, of course, was one of these users.  I therefore maintain that this is not a proper duplicate of the other question, and this question should be kept as a unique question about a unique problem since that in fact is what it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing colors from output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998978/removing-colors-from-output), [How do I turn OFF colors for ls output in Terminal on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33160450/608639), [How to remove dir background in `ls -color` output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40574819/608639), [How to turn off color with `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107371/56041) and friends.

Comment: @jww I would say though this post and the possible duplicate have the same solution, it is the same solution to *two different problems*.  Some user looking through stack overflow could have the same problem I have and still have no idea that he should be looking at a question about colors in `ls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the ANSI escape sequences that turn colours on and off. Try adding

```
--color=never
```

to `ls` to turn colouring off.

Usually, you should use `--color=auto` which should turn the colours off when the output is not a terminal.

Comment: Well, that did it!  Thanks!