# Remove all except one file in bash on mac

Tags: bash

bash on mac, installed by brew

```
λ  brew list | grep bash
bash

λ  which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

```
λ  rm !("shorturl.api")
-bash: !: event not found
```

```
λ  ls -1 | grep -v shorturl.api | xargs rm
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[0m'$'\033''[01;32mapi'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[01;34metc'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[01;34minternal'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[00mshorturl.go'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Just because it would run `/usr/local/bin/bash` if you typed `bash`, that does not mean you are currently running `/usr/local/bin/bash`. The shell you are running might have been started by running something other than `bash`.

Comment: Your filenames look like they contain colour escape sequences, because you have parsed the output of `ls` which is a *"bad idea"* **TM**.

Comment: The negative wildcard pattern requires extended globbing syntax (`shopt extglob`); see ["How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995) In the `ls` version, you apparently have `ls` set to output in color, and so the color escape sequences are messing things up; see ["Extra escape characters from `ls` command making life hard"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634528). This is one of many things that can go wrong parsing the output of `ls`, so [don't do that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @MarkSetchell my login shell is bash, echo $SHELL is /usr/local/bin/bash.

Comment: thanks @GordonDavisson, now i know where these escape characters from and how  to turn if off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!(pattern-list)` globbing pattern only works when extended globbing is enabled.  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).  In this case you need:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -- !(shorturl.api)
```

- The `--` with `rm` is to prevent files whose names begin with `-` being treated as options.

One way to do it without extended globbing is:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name shorturl.api -delete
```

The `ls -1 | grep -v shorturl.api | xargs rm` attempt in the question is broken in several ways, including:

- The output of `ls` is intended for reading by humans.  It is not suitable for automatic processing.  See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
- The `grep -v shorturl.api` will exclude files other than the intended one.  For instance, `old-shorturl.api` would be excluded.
- `xargs` by default uses spaces and newlines to split its input into arguments.  `xargs rm` won't delete files that have such characters in their names.

Comment: what a pity that ls output is not suitable for xargs processing

Comment: @dfang, agreed.  See [Is there a reason why ls does not have a --zero or -0 option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112125) for more information.  `find` is much better for listing and filtering anyway, but sorting the output of `find` according to time or size etc. is tricky to do correctly.

Answer (score -1):

thanks @GordonDavisson.

use ls --color before pipeline to xargs

```
ls -1 --color=never | grep -v shorturl.api | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: This is broken in several ways.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71580420/4154375) for some of them.

Comment: with --color=never, it works on my laptop :)

Comment: and with `shopt -s extglob` in ` ~/.bash_profile`, `rm -- !("1.txt")` is more simple, thanks